# Can you reduce Websocket polling request

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm using Websockets to send communications from the website to my backend server I've built using nodejs KOA.  I'm using websockets library 1.4.x and it is being hosted in an AWS elasticbeanstalk.  The problem I have is there are too many polling requests per second and AWS Elasticbeanstalk has classified my cluster as Degraded.  The website usage is very low, and I'm not actually pushing anything to the site.  I'm using the websockets to send report data back.  I probably should change it to use POST or AJAX instead, which will solve my problem.  But, I was wondering if anyone could help explain why I am seeing so many polling requests?  For every client with the site loaded, it sends a polling request every second:

```
2016-05-24T03:33:37.025471Z 0.000037 0.001259 0.000019 400 400 3 41 "POST http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqo-g&sid=2p4uqRwRpgAGe9MYGEFw HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.058664Z 0.000046 0.000801 0.000021 400 400 0 41 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=VGMrEcNWfe3V52xIBrsr HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.068053Z 0.000026 0.001814 0.000017 400 400 3 41 "POST http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqq6w&sid=VGMrEcNWfe3V52xIBrsr HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.114333Z 0.000027 0.001408 0.000028 200 200 0 101 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqptG HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.204186Z 0.000049 0.000999 0.000018 400 400 0 41 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqpwy&sid=70GDwJbapBpe7xr0Brss HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.222283Z 0.000027 0.002033 0.000019 200 200 0 101 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqpdt HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.284256Z 0.00004 0.001299 0.00002 400 400 0 34 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=70GDwJbapBpe7xr0Brss HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.304609Z 0.000025 0.000778 0.000016 400 400 3 41 "POST http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqpyM&sid=70GDwJbapBpe7xr0Brss HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.334223Z 0.00003 0.001927 0.000021 200 200 0 5 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqpfN&sid=t4oUghKESf3iQDNIGEFx HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.412382Z 0.000025 0.001156 0.000027 400 400 0 41 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=t4oUghKESf3iQDNIGEFx HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.460320Z 0.000025 0.001016 0.000029 400 400 0 41 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqph5&sid=t4oUghKESf3iQDNIGEFx HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.562313Z 0.000061 0.002397 0.000026 200 200 3 2 "POST http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqpj7&sid=t4oUghKESf3iQDNIGEFx HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.878069Z 0.000057 0.001508 0.000019 200 200 0 101 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqqIm HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
2016-05-24T03:33:37.978133Z 0.000043 0.001061 0.000033 400 400 0 41 "GET http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com:80/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJWqqKp&sid=az8li1OVGN8CuKc7Brst HTTP/1.1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36" - -
```

Server side code is:

```
var http = require('http');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();

app.use(router.routes())
   .use(router.allowedMethods());

router.get('/', getHomepage );
router.get('/:storeid', getHomepage );

app.context.render = render({
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'views'),
  autoescape: true,
  cache: 'memory', // disable, set to false
  ext: 'html',
//  locals: locals,
//  filters: filters,
//  tags: tags,
//  extensions: extensions
});

app.use(staticFolder('./public'));

var server = http.createServer(app.callback());
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var storeId=0;

io.on('connection', function (socket)
{
    socket.on('submit', function(data)
    {
        // Do something
    }
));
```

On the client I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> var socket = new io('http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com'); </script>
```

Comment: You aren't using WebSockets. If you were using websockets you wouldn't be polling. The point of WS is so you don't have to poll. Your "WebSockets Library 1.4.x" is not using websockets. But we don't know what you mean by  "WebSockets Library 1.4.x". Please include more information on how you are setting up you "websockets".

Comment: It looks like your client is using socket.io (not plain webSocket) and, for some reason, your client is only requesting the `polling` transport, not the webSocket transport.  Please show us the relevant client code that is making the connection.  It could also be that your server library does not support a socket.io  connection.  socket.io is not the same as webSocket.  If you're requesting a socket.io connection from the client (which you are), then you MUST have socket.io support on the server to get a webSocket connection.

Comment: I'm using "socket.io": "1.4.x",

Comment: You can enforce using real websockets on socket.io like this: `var socket = io('http://xxx.elb.amazonaws.com', {transports: ['websocket']});`. Also do not use `new io`, use just `io` - socket.io does not use `new` in their examples.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Amazon ELB doesn't support WebSockets!!!